# Does a bijective homomorphism in Category theory have to be a bijection of arrows as well as objects?

Tags: category-theory

In giving an example of two non-isomorphic posets related by a bijective homomorphism the following was proposed.

$A=\{a,b,c\}$ with $a\leq b$, $a\leq c$ and $b$ and $c$ not comparable.

$B=\{x,y,z\}$ with $x\leq y\leq z$.

Regarding $A$ and $B$ as categories the $\leq$ in $a\leq b$ is regarded as an arrow from $a$ to $b$.

In thinking of an example I thought of this but rejected it because there is not a bijective correspondence in arrows. It is not clear to me from Awodey's book but I thought there had to be a bijection of objects and arrows. Is that not the case? Is it the case that in Category Theory "bijective" applies only to objects? If so it seems odd in a field that puts such emphasis on the arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to handle posets as categories in this example.

A bijective homomorphism between *posets* is meant to be bijective only on the *elements* of the poset, so your example works.